# PHP strpos match all needles in multiple haystacks

Tags: php, arrays, match, strpos

I want to check if ALL words from $words exist in one or more $sentences, word order is not important.

Words will only contain [a-z0-9].

Sentences will only contain [a-z0-9-].

My code so far, it almost work as expected:

```
$words = array("3d", "4");
$sentences = array("x-3d-abstract--part--282345", "3d-speed--boat-430419", "beautiful-flower-462451", "3d-d--384967");

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $sentences_found = array_values(array_filter($sentences, function($find_words) use ($word) {return strpos($find_words, $word);}));
}
print_r($sentences_found);
```

If you run this code here http://3v4l.org/tD5t5 , you'll get 4 results, but in reality it should be 3 results

```
Array
(
    [0] => x-3d-abstract--part--282345
    [1] => 3d-speed--boat-430419
    [2] => beautiful-flower-462451   // this one is wrong, no "3d" in here, only "4"
    [3] => 3d-d--384967
)
```

How can I do this?

Also is there any better way to do this than strpos?

Regex?

Regex is maybe slow for this job because sometimes there will be 1000's of $sentences (don't ask why).

Comment: huh? I run your codes, result of `print_r()` is: `Array
(
    [0] => this-is-simple-simple-sentence-123-aa99-311qwerty
)` instead of 3 items

Comment: are you sure about it? i get all 3 results with print_r()

Comment: @Sunny Works also for me! (See: http://3v4l.org/b2AoN)

Comment: i think i need to re-check my code then, this code i showed you is just a part of bigger code, something is interfering with my results :) at least this code work as expected then :)

Comment: ok i tested just this code on my server and it works perfectly, so i answered my own question then haha

Comment: Then I think you can delete your question here, since it was only a mistake

Comment: no, wait, i found an error, i'll post another example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an intersection of found sentences per word:

```
$found = array();

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $found[$word] = array_filter($sentences, function($sentence) use ($word) {
        return strpos($sentence, $word) !== false;
    });
}

print_r(call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $found));
```

Or, approach from `$sentences`:

```
$found = array_filter($sentences, function($sentence) use ($words) {
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (strpos($sentence, $word) === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // all words found in sentence 
    return true;
});

print_r($found);
```

One important thing to mention is that your search criteria was wrong; instead of `strpos($sentence, $word)` you should explicitly compare against `false`, otherwise you will miss a match at the start of a sentence.

Comment: amazing work! tyvm it works perfectly, i've tried various combinations and everything is ok, i'll give you the biggest upvote ever! :)